# CORS issue with Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am given a URL - Swagger Ui for an applicaiton. I am able to open the url in my mobile but when I tried the same from my system, I am getting the below error.

*"Fetch errorPossible cross-origin (CORS) issue? The URL origin (https://xxx.xxx.xxx) does not match the page (https://yyy.yyy.yyy). Check the server returns the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-*' headers."*

Can somebody help me fix this error. Since I am able to access this from my mobile, I am not sure whether something needs to be done at server side or browser side.

Any pointers or help would be much helpful.

Comment: The API server (https://xxx.xxx.xxx) must support CORS, that is, allow cross-domain requests from the Swagger UI page (https://yyy.yyy.yyy). See https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That is what I understood. But this is accessible from my mobile and personal machine. So am not able to identify the problem.